# How to define the “largest” set in python?

Tags: python, set, max

Consider following code:

```
b = set([111,222,333,444])
a = set([10,20,30])
print max(a,b,key=len) # set([444, 333, 222, 111])
print max(a,b) # set([10, 20, 30])
```

I am curious, if there is no ‘key’ parameter, the max() function will return a confusing result, it is not the one contains more items, neither the one whose first item is bigger (10<111), neither the first argument (if it doesn’t know how to compare the input arguments, maybe it will return the first argument which is b?)

By the explanation of `max()` function, it should return “the largest argument” if the input is two or more argument. So how to define the ‘largest’ among several sets?

Comment: FYI: `max(b,a)` returned `set([444, 333, 222, 111])` so it seems that the first argument will be returned if the params are not scalar and no comparison function is given... which seems slightly worse than raising a doesNotComputeException but that's just my personal preference.

Comment: @meissner: if no ordering support is implemented a `TypeError` exception would be raised. Sets do implement ordering hooks but have given the operations a different meaning: whether or not one operand is a subset of the other.

Comment: @meissner: since neither `a > b` nor `b > a` is true here (neither set is a subset of the other), the first element is returned (max breaks ties between equal maximums by picking the first).

Answer (score 5):

Sets override `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` to make *subset* and *superset* comparisons and should not be seen as orderable.

Because of this, *there is no 'max' or 'min' set*.

From the [set type documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

> **`issubset(other)`**
>   **`set <= other`**
>
> Test whether every element in the set is in other.
>
> **`set < other`**
>
> Test whether the set is a proper subset of other, that is, `set <= other and set != other`.
>
> **`issuperset(other)`**
>   **`set >= other`**
>
> Test whether every element in other is in the set.
>
> **`set > other`**
>
> Test whether the set is a proper superset of other, that is, `set >= other and set != other`.

and further down

> A set is less than another set if and only if the first set is a proper subset of the second set (is a subset, but is not equal). A set is greater than another set if and only if the first set is a proper superset of the second set (is a superset, but is not equal).

and finally

> Since sets only define partial ordering (subset relationships), the output of the `list.sort()` method is undefined for lists of sets.

`max()` and `min()` use the same definitions of ordering to determine the largest or smallest item from a series of inputs, and because sets define ordering in terms of subset relationships, the output of `max()` and `min()` is undefined too.